# Azure Service bus Queue - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination exception

Tags: java, spring, azure, servicebus

I'm able to connect and consume messages from Azure service bus queue. But following error is appearing randomly while message processing is in progress. After the error appears it looks like either the messages are not getting consumed further or they are pushed to DLQ. Restarting listener application is causing the same exception to appear.

I'm using Spring DefaultMessageListenerContainer with Apache Qpid

> 2016-05-05 01:49:36.303 WARN 14716 — [nerContainer-61]
>   o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer : Setup of JMS message
>   listener invoker failed for destination
>   'org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.QueueImpl@5f61cba7' - trying to
>   recover. Cause: Timeout waiting for attach
>
> Unknown endpoint
>   Transfer{handle=0,deliveryId=36,deliveryTag=P\xb8)T\xd9\xea%A\x95\xe5Fj]\x91\x00\x15,messageFormat=0,more=false,batchable=true}
>   Unknown endpoint
>   Transfer{handle=0,deliveryId=36,deliveryTag=\xdc\x9b\x9d\xf5\x817\x9bO\x97.\x19\xeam<\x00\x81,messageFormat=0,more=false,batchable=true}
>
> javax.jms.IllegalStateException: Closed at
>   org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.checkClosed(SessionImpl.java:326)
>   at
>   org.apache.qpid.amqp_1_0.jms.impl.SessionImpl.getTransacted(SessionImpl.java:222)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.commitIfNecessary(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:757)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:665)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:315)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:253)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1158)
>   at
>   org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1052)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

UPDATED:

```
`public DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer() throws NamingException {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    messageListenerContainer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    Destination queue = (Destination) context.lookup("STORAGE_NEW_QUEUE");
    messageListenerContainer.setDestination(queue);
    messageListenerContainer.setConcurrency(concurrency);
    messageListenerContainer.setSessionAcknowledgeMode(Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    messageListenerContainer.setCacheLevel(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.CACHE_SESSION);
        messageListenerContainer.setErrorHandler(new EDIMessageErrorHandler());
    MessageListenerAdapter adapter = new MessageListenerAdapter();
    adapter.setDelegate(new EDIMessageListener());
    adapter.setDefaultListenerMethod("onMessage");
    messageListenerContainer.setMessageListener(adapter);
    return messageListenerContainer;
}`
```

Please advise on what could be the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Q: So what do the logs on the Azure side say?  Your Spring/QPid logs merely say "I timed out trying to communicate".  This is the "result" of the problem.  You need to find the *CAUSE*. It sounds like you need to look at 1) Your Azure service, and 2) your network communications between AZure and QPid...  Besides looking at the logs and/or instrumenting your Azure service, you might also want to take a [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) trace.

Comment: Sorry for late response. Can you please advise how I can get logs of Service Bus queue on Azure.I can only see a link for Operation Logs on the namespace which are not available.Please note that message listener is running on Azure VM. I've updated my DMLC configuration.

Comment: @pkumar Where you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what reason caused the issue without any codes.

However, there is an offical document [`Service Bus messaging exceptions`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-messaging-exceptions/) that lists some exceptions generated by the Microsoft Azure Service Bus messaging APIs, and the section [`Exception types`](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-bus-messaging-exceptions/#exception-types) lists messaging exception types, and their causes, and notes suggested action you can take. I think you can refer to it for inspecting your issue.

According to the exception information `Unknown endpoint`, per my exception, I think the reason might be in the configuration for the AMQP connection with QPID. I searched for the possible reason, and got the helpful link https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/qpid-users/201009.mbox/%3CAANLkTimNsHx3BeXCuYxbPOo+_3+vpH-Eu0AQcJfA07Oe@mail.gmail.com%3E. Hope it help.

Could you share the key codes for investaging the issue?

Any concern, please feel free to let me know.