# Microsoft Azure Service Bus Session closed and not restored

Tags: java, spring, azure, azureservicebus, spring-jms

I am running into an issue where, listener session closing abruptly and connection not restored and no error code. Didn't find a good solution. below is exception log

```
javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.checkClosed(JmsSession.java:1101) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.rollback(JmsSession.java:263) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolSession.close(JmsPoolSession.java:112) ~[pooled-jms-1.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsUtils.closeSession(JmsUtils.java:109) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.clearResources(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1289) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1135) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]

2023-10-03 21:41:40.521  WARN 1 --- [ontainer#0-4019] o.s.j.l.DefaultMessageListenerContainer  : Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination 'carton-status-update' - trying to recover. Cause: The MessageConsumer is closed
2023-10-03 21:41:40.525  WARN 1 --- [ontainer#0-4019] o.m.pooled.jms.JmsPoolSession            : Caught exception trying rollback() when putting session back into the pool, will invalidate. javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed

javax.jms.IllegalStateException: The Session is closed
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.checkClosed(JmsSession.java:1101) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.qpid.jms.JmsSession.rollback(JmsSession.java:263) ~[qpid-jms-client-0.53.0.jar!/:na]
    at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolSession.close(JmsPoolSession.java:112) ~[pooled-jms-1.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnection.cleanupAllLoanedSessions(JmsPoolConnection.java:269) ~[pooled-jms-1.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnection.close(JmsPoolConnection.java:80) ~[pooled-jms-1.2.4.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.releaseConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.refreshSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:394) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.refreshConnectionUntilSuccessful(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:985) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.recoverAfterListenerSetupFailure(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:959) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1146) ~[spring-jms-5.3.27.jar!/:5.3.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Below is my JMS listener annotation in my spring boot service

```
    @JmsListener(destination = TOPIC_NAME, containerFactory = "topicJmsListenerContainerFactory", subscription = SUBSCRIPTION_NAME, concurrency="15-20")
```

Restore is not happening only where concurrency parameter is configured

Please help if there is something to do to automatically restore the session when concurrency is configured.

PS: Following another similar question posted and replied by @[peter-pan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4989676/peter-pan) in below link
[Azure Service bus Queue - Setup of JMS message listener invoker failed for destination exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038803/azure-service-bus-queue-setup-of-jms-message-listener-invoker-failed-for-desti)